# Attempting to create an AAC 5.1 file from a 6 channel WAV file but only getting stereo

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create an AAC 5.1 with Constant Bit Rate (CBR), from six-channel WAV file, but I get a stereo file.

```
ffmpeg -channel_layout 5.1 -i input5.1.wav -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 448k output.m4a
```

Help please, where did I make a mistake?

Posted Image media info of M4A file:

[image]

Posted Image media info of AAC file:

[image]

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: When I change the extension to "AAC", I get a six-channel file. A stereo file is obtained only with the extension "m4a".
In both cases, no errors or warnings appear when creating AAC or M4A.

Comment: I added an image a little higher on the link.

Comment: Mediainfo bug. Both outputs are identical.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think you're right! The whole command code correctly written?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm late. I'm new to ffmpeg, but I use `-ac 6` to designate 5.1 audio channels in movies. Example:

```
ffmpeg -i [input.mkv] -c:a aac -b:a 640k -ac 6 [output.mkv]
```

Also, I didn't see `-channel_layout 5.1` in the docs. Let me know if I could attempt to be of more assistance.

Comment: Joe, thanks for the help. I tried with the key "-ac 6", the result is the same as on my screenshot. I think it's still a bug mediainfo. When I added the video stream later, mediainfo showed 6 channels correctly. The mediainfo bug only appears with a single audio stream.